# Loop for plots consisting of 10 data sets

Tags: r, loops, plot

If I have a series of data sets called "species1", "species2", etc. until "species10", how can I make a loop so that it plots each of them?
I have the code below, but I think the portion where I have "data="" is incorrect.
(logabun and TEM are two of the columns I have in each data set)

```
par(mfrow=c(5,2),mar=c(1,1,1,1),mgp=c(5,1.5,0))
for(i in 1:10)
{plot(logabun~TEM, data=(paste("species",i,sep="")))}
```

Comment: `paste("species",i,sep="")` is just a string.  You need `get(paste("species",i,sep=""))`

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there is an answer ...

The code is the question did not work because `paste("species",i,sep="")` is just a string. In order to get the variable with that name, you need to use 
`get(paste("species",i,sep=""))`